# Adding Solution Items in a project template wizard

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility, project-template

I'm trying to add a file to a Visual Studio "Solution Items" folder, using a Project Template Wizard. I'm able to create the folder itself, but when I add a file, it doesn't do anything.

My code (executed from `ProjectFinishedGenerating`) is

```
    fullPath = @"path_to_existing_file";
    _solutionFolder.AddFromFile(fullPath);
```

Where _solutionFolder is a Project instance corresponding the the solution folder.

Comment: I created a thread a MSDN, but haven't had a chance to try it. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vsx/thread/1a86e59e-bb9b-41b7-8bde-220f351a3c34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit the same snag. You need to add it to the ProjectItems:

```
var _solutionFolder = _vsSolution.AddSolutionFolder(folder);
_solutionFolder.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(fullPath);
```

Note, I haven't tried the above code. I'm adapting it from my code (which runs in an AddIn):

```
Dim project As EnvDTE.Project = _vsSolution.AddSolutionFolder(folderName)
_folder = CType(project.Object, SolutionFolder)
_folder.Parent.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(file)
```

Comment: there is no AddSolutionFolder method.